# Where is kill_proc_info defined?

Tags: linux-device-driver

what is header file for the kernel API function kill_proc_info(int sig, struct siginfo *info, pid_t pid)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably found this in `linux/signal.c` and `include/linux/sched.h`

Answer (score 0):

Grep is your friend. Or use one of the cross-references like http://lxr.linux.no or http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/.

Ad edit (the original question did *not* say "API"):
Actually, that function is **not an API**. It's an implementation detail of `signal.c`. It is not an API, because there is no `EXPORT_SYMBOL`[`_GPL`] declaration for it, so it's not callable from modular code.

Answer (score -1):

[edit]
`man` won't work - however, `man kill_proc_info` into your favorite search engine will. note too that posting a page that doesn't render correctly in somebodies browser will also result in a downvote.
[/edit]

`man` is your friend

[edit]
google is your friend (which is how I found the first answer - in the comments below) but we're not allowed to use that as an answer here.  Better to have a repository of lazy people than to request they attempt to use the tools that they are given - IOW, better to give a man a fish than teach him how to fish
[/edit]

Comment: -1: `man` doesn't contain kernel functions, syscalls (like sys_bind), etc.

Comment: @maverick - And yet, when I google 'man kill_proc_info' I get http://man.developpez.com/include/linux/sched.php.  (But, I guess I would have been downvoted for mentioning google too)

Comment: In the first: `http://man.developpez.com/include/linux/sched.php` is unreadable (as for me: Firefox 4.0 at ArchLinux). In the second: you've been downvoted because you suggestion is useless not because you've mentioned `man`. What's a pity I can't downvote once again, not because of `google` word, just because the page you mentioned is unreadable - one more useless suggestion.

Comment: @mohwastz - the answer is in the comment immediately before yours

Comment: @maverick - can't help you there, my browser renders the page just fine (note too that the name of the include file is embedded in the URL)

Comment: @mohwastz: At least from me, you'd get an **upvote** for mentioning google, because it's correct (man is incorrect) and this question does not really deserve any answer beyond "STFS".

Comment: @Jan - I'm sorely disappointed that I didn't post my original answer - which was 'google it'.  Unfortunately, I googled it and then posted that answer which was deemed unworthy.  Curious though, I can't find STFS?